# Running Zend Server alongside Softaculous AMPPS?

Tags: php, apache, zend-server, softaculous

I currently do most of my local server testing using Softaculous AMPPS. However, I would like to see if I can install and run Zend Server under the same AMPPS Apache installation without disrupting anything.

I really want the Zend Optimizer, Loader and other advanced debugging features provided with Zend Server but the easy extensibility and configuration of AMPPS.

Is this possible? If so, what would you recommend to achieve this?

I'm on Windows 8.